# How to write this Rails asset pipeline link

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Rails 4.2
This asset pipeline stuff I continue to not figure out.
How would I write this?

```
 <!-- For image lightbox you need to include "a" tag pointing to image link, along with the class "prettyphoto".-->
            <div class="gallery">
              <!-- Full size image link in anchor tag. Thumbnail link in image tag. -->
              <a href="img/portfolio/1.jpg" class="prettyphoto"><img src="img/portfolio/1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

I've tried it twenty ways but I can't get it. A small image is suppose to come up and then when you click on it the image is larger. And I need to use the two existing classes as this is a bootstrap template conversion into Rails.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in public/assets/images you can access it by saying:

```
<%= image_tag 'name_of_image.png', class: 'name-of-class' %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

```
<%= link_to 'name_of_image.png', object_path, class: 'name-of-class' %>
```

Comment: I know how to do a simple image_tag but the question is not that. The answer I need has to produce a href and a src while using two classes. Look closer at the code I posted. Thx.

Comment: Easiest way to have a small image come up would be to add a jquery click event to the class. Something like $('.name-of-class).on('click', function(){ 
// do something, add class or modify size attributes of the image})

Comment: You could also have two images but have one w/ display none and on the click event hide the smaller image and show the larger one. Lots of easy ways to do this w/ javascript. Possible w/ pure css but easiest (for me, at least) to just use javascript / jquery.

Comment: No, this is a bootstrap template conversion and it uses Lightbox and so I need to use what is there and use both classes. It doesn't work without both classes.

Comment: Template or not you can still use jquery.